# Firebase - sendVerificationCode API

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

I am trying to authenticate the user with phone number using firebase through sendVerificationCode API. It is expecting phoneNumber and either of (iosReceipt and iosSecret) or recaptchaToken or safetyNetToken.

My app is on the Web, Android and also in IOS. I don't want to depend on the front-end to generate recaptchaToken or some other things. All these apps should just call one custom API with just phoneNumber and it should sendVerificationCode to the user. I am trying to implement a wrapper API to sendVerificationCode.

Can anyone help me with how to achieve this? Am I going on the right path?

Thanks in Advance!

Source: *https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/sendVerificationCode?hl=en_US*